# How to edit a JS file with a shell script

Tags: javascript, shell

I have a configuration file in JS that exports an array of of objects:

```
const configuration: ConfigData[] = [
    {
        pathToPage: 'some/path',
        pathToComponent: 'components/some-component',
        roles: [Roles.Admin],
    },
    {
        pathToPage: 'some/path/2',
        pathToComponent: iframeLoader,
        roles: [Roles.User],
    },
];

export default configuration;
```

I'd like to add a new object at the end of the array using a shell script, so that my file looks likes this:

```
const configuration: ConfigData[] = [
    {
        pathToPage: 'some/path',
        pathToComponent: 'components/some-component',
        roles: [Roles.Admin],
    },
    {
        pathToPage: 'some/path/2',
        pathToComponent: iframeLoader,
        roles: [Roles.User],
    },
    {
        pathToPage: 'some/path/3',
        pathToComponent: iframeLoader,
        roles: [Roles.User, Roles.Admin],
    },
];

export default configuration;
```

Is that possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk -v addfile='cfg.add' '/^];$/{ system("cat " addfile) }1' cfg.js` inserts the contents of file cfg.add just before the line in cfg.js consisting of `];` and prints the combined output to stdout.